# Select group of data what contains variable where is same id

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on football odds/stats/livescore website, i am currently working on **League Standings** table and i have problem.

In database sometimes i have more **same LeagueID's** columns, for same LeagueID's there is column Sub_Id or LeagueName what is unique and also one of the keys.

Is possible to do something like

```
select * from table where LeagueID={$leagueid} group by Sub_Id having
TeamID = {$team}
```

So i want to get just League standings what contains TeamID? This code up will return me just one row, i want to get 16 teams where is my team.

I get now 3x16 teams...

Problem is that i can't pass Sub_id to database, just LeagueID and TeamID.
It will be much easier to say

select * from table where Sub_Id = $subid, but i can't do that, only using inner join. Let's say that i won't use inner join.

See this [image]

I want just first 16 teams, so as paramater to database i pass LeagueID and TeamID.

Comment: Beware of the awful, confusing,  nonstandard MySQL extension to `GROUP BY`. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: I saw it, but i didn't see solution.. Check image what i really want.
Just League standing what contains myteamid

Answer (score 0):

Use this query :

```
SELECT * FROM table where LeagueID={$leagueid} and TeamID = {$team} group by Sub_Id
```

Comment: That returns me just one Team, i want 16 teams in group where is $teamid

Check image, there is 3x16 teams, i want just one group of 16